# Getting 401.1 error after ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application hosted in Azure App Service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have created an app using ASP.NET Core 6 MVC  application. I am using the Microsoft.Identity platform for authentication (Azure AD authentication). It worked fine locally. User is able to sign-in and sign-out and able to navigate. When signing in with wrong password or username then user getting an error.
But when hosted the same code on Azure App Service and when accessing the app the 401 error occured. HOw I fix that issue. As I mentioned everything works fine locally so no issue with registration clientId or any other registration level info.

[image]

WebConfig file

[image]

AppService configuration
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you encounter a 401.1 error when accessing directly after deployment, or do you encounter a 401.1 error after using the wrong login and password?

Comment: I don't get to the point where I could login.  This is the first thing I see after I launch the app from my browser.

Comment: Please login the kudu site which url like `https://your_app_name.scm.azurewebsites.net`, then check the web.config file under the wwwroot.  You can show us the content in web.config, and pls hide the sensitive info.

Comment: [I also need to check the Application settings inside the configuration in azure portal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVAUo.png)

Comment: Jason, I have updated the original post with the web config file and  Application screen shot.

Comment: Please enable `stdoutlogenabled= true`, and restart the webapp, I want to check the logs. You can find it under  `\log\stdout`.

Comment: Jason.  I could not locate the \log\stdout? Can you help me get to it please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245299/discussion-between-jason-and-salma).

Comment: Another I would mentioned in the main post there is a snapshot of the 401.1 error.  It shows the Requested Url as Https:/mywebsite:80 whereas the url I am trying to access is https://mywebsite.AzureFreeWebSite.net/.

Comment: I cannot chat when i click on the chat window, I cannot access it due to the proxy policy.

Comment: [Check this blog](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-app-service-configure-detailed-error-logging/), we need detailed logs.

Comment: I tried to follow the document it talked abot how to access the Eventlog. Actually I couldnt find anything in Eventlog. I was able to set the stdoutlogenabled=true in the webconfig file from cloud explorer. After restarting the app I again searched through the log files and I was able to find the two more logs that could help. Both of them pointing to 401.71 . I have updated the original post with the screen shot.  Also note that the url is https://mywebsite.azurfreewebsite.net/  it is https. Also I am using the Microsoft.Identity.Platform for Azure AD Authentication.

Comment: [It seems there are some code issue about the auth, pls check this blog, and follow the steps to check the  log files.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1067492/Azure-AD-Securing-Your-API-with-Zero-Code)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the question, if you enabled Azure Active Directory, there is no need to you to login and logout explicitly. As you are trying to do those operations locally, it must be they are not configured perfectly locally also. The same error it is causing while moving and accessing in Azure App Service.

Kindly check the following things in configuration:

**1. Configuration of IIS before deployment**

**2. Configuration of AAD**

These two steps could solve the issue.